# Angular Use page generated HTML for component template

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular, templates

So, I'm upgrading from AngularJS to Angular 2. We had to not upgrade directly to 4 for some internal reasons.

Anyway. We have some parts of the HTML that needs to be generated by the backend before being presented. So, this obviously means that I can't go the route of static HTML or HTML files. I've attempted to use my best Googling skills to find a solution but have come up empty.

For example (PHP):

```
<div id="appRoot">
    <div id="mainView">
<?php
if ($user->isActive()) :
    ?>
        <p>Welcome, <?php print $user->getName(); ?>!</p>
<?php
else:
    ?>
        <p>Hello newbie!</p>
<?php
endif; ?>
        <... begin main Angular Template ... >
    </div>
    <div id="sideContent">
        <... begin side Angular Template ... >
    </div>
</div>
```

It gets a little more complicated than that in places, but that's the gist. There are parts of the template that won't get rendered or will get rendered with different values that aren't dependent on the Angular app but the backend.

I'm hoping that there's a way to do this, but my search thus far has yielded goose-egg. If this is true and it can't be done, I really don't get why one of the most versatile parts of the AngularJS approach was removed.

Anyway, any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Fleshed-out the example a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, what we wanted to do wasn't really possible. The particular case that we needed to solve was having multiple possible root elements for the user to interact with, but we didn't want to expose the logic for determining whether the elements should be shown or not to the end user.

We had to go with a, slightly, hack-ish solution that utilized generating new root components with specific selectors for each element (i.e. `selector: "div#element1"`). This was the most widely available and, apparently, used solution for this specific issue. It's apparently known by the Angular team, and it's unclear whether they will be addressing it in the future.

The end solution was to find all the elements on the page that needed the root elements, iterate over them and assign a unique selector (using utilizing the ID selector), then adding a new component class with that selector to the list of components to bootstrap.

i.e.

```
const BOOTSTRAP_ELEMENTS: any[] = [];
const DECLARATION_COMPONENTS: any[] = [];
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName('.custom-elements');
elements.map(
    (index: number, element: Element) => {
        let selector = 'custom-element#' + element.getAttribute('id');
        let component = getCustomComponentForSelector('.selector');
        BOOTSTRAP_ELEMENT.push(component);
        DELCARATION_COMPONENTS.push(component);
        element.className += selector;
    }
);

@NgModule({
    ...
    declarations: DECLARATION_COMPONENTS,
    bootstrap: BOOTSTRAP_COMPONENTS,
    ...
})
export class MyModule {}
```